# Implicit real conversion to integer in (IBM)-Fortran-IV

Tags: floating-point, integer, fortran, type-conversion, fortran77

I'm rewriting an old IBM-Fortran program to modern Fortran-90 and I've encountered the following expressions:

```
N1=A/B+1.000001
N2=A/B+1. -1.E-5
N3=A/B+1.E-05
```

As far as I know, in the <s>old</s> Fortran way of implicit declaration, variables starting with `I`-`N` are taken as integers. That means we're looking at an implicit conversion from floating point numbers `A`,`B` to integers `N1`-`N3`.

My question is now, how do I translate these expression, using explicit real-integer conversions?
My attempt was:

```
N1=ceiling(A/B+1.)
N2=floor(A/B+1.)
N3=ceiling(A/B)
```

Can anyone please clarify this? I haven't found any hints regarding this on the internet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type conversion intrinsic function "int" changes values just as assignment to an integer does.

P.S.  While implicit typing is still supported, I consider it "old".  It is best avoided -- use "implicit none".

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure if `int()` leads to the correct results when using higher floating point precision, i.e. `double precision` variables. I think the above code is toying with the fact, that the floating point numbers had a limited accuracy of, I think, `1. +- 1E-4`, which led me to the assumption that a `floor()` or `ceiling()`-kind of behaviour was intended.

Comment: Sure, it is an deprecated way of coding, but the implicit declaration according to the first variable letter is still valid code, which made me strike out that _old_.

Comment: No, the implicit conversion is identical to `int`. It is a generic function, for all real kinds and other numeric types, as are the other functions.

Comment: Yes, I know. When using the implicit conversion, numbers past the dot simply get cut off, which is what `int` does. But then again, what is the point of the `+1.E-5` and `-1.E-5`?

Comment: @Jost, since floating point precision is limited, it could be that some number like `3.0` is internally stored like `2.99999987` or something. Integer truncation would result in a value of `2` instead of `3`. That's why a small correction is added, just to bump up some of the least significant bits of the mantissa. (Note: this example is very bad since 3.0 is exactly representable in IEEE 754 as 1.1_2 x 2^1 but still shows the general idea).

Comment: I must say the N1&N3 cases make sense, if within tol of an integer round to that integer.   For N2 it says if we are axactly an integer within 1e-5 then round down to the next integer? I'd study the code to see if thats really the intent, unless of course your job is to port it as is bugs and all.

Comment: If the existing code is tested by long use, why change it?   "ceiling" and "floor" are more elegant then using the correction constants, but every time you change a large legacy code you risk introducing a bug. That's why my inclination was to use "int" without changing the calculation -- you will get exactly the same result.  Using "int" could suppress warning messages, depending on compiler and what options you have selected.  Do you have a regression test suite?

Comment: I support this answer :-) -- Although (as far as I know), most programmers don't worry about implicit type conversion.  They worry about implicit type *declaration* (which is what you avoid using `Implicit None`).  I would say just declare the variables as `real :: A,B` and be done with it...